# Creating a Scheduled Task in windows phone

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, windows-phone-7.1

How can I repeat a particular task daily at a particular time in windows phone?I need to show a toast message to the user everyday at particular time.

Answer (score 0):

[Just use PeriodicTask class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.scheduler.periodictask%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) and configure it to run in background.

sample to check:

[Windows Phone 8 Background Agent (Part 1: Periodic Task)](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/656654/Windows-Phone-Background-Agent-Part-Periodic-T)

Comment: I have already read the content in the given link. But in that example toast notification shows after every minute, I need to get this notification at particular time only, say for 10 A.M everyday